# red5 on server A, video files on server B?

Tags: video-streaming, red5

Would that be possible to install red5 on **`server A`** and upload my .flv video files to **`server B`**, then can I use server A to stream the videos?

---

thanks for the replies. but considering the bandwidth being used 2x, I think I should think of another solutions. I totally missed that fact!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but hosting a server and a video on different servers results in 2x bandwidth than when you host the video server and the video files on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

If the connectivity between the servers is fast enough, you can easily do it with file sharing (NFS or SMB).

Answer (score 1):

As @onon15 did suggest, you can of course simply mount a network drive on both servers, or make some RSync script.

Another possibility is to use Red5's clustering. You should search for: "Red5 Edge/Orion clustering" to find more information about it in the net.

In short, the Edge/Orion clustering uses a RTMPClient on the nodes (the edges) of the cluster to provide a connection to a central server (the Orion). So you could also call this Master/Slave Clustering.
The Slaves itself can then connect multiple users, but for the master it just looks like a single connection (that at least IMHO).

Sebastian